# How do I ensure that I redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS?

Tags: redirects, https, nginx, cloudflare

I use CloudFlare for DNS for a variety of sites. I am using all three free Page Rules for custom caching, and I am trying to avoid upgrading to their Pro service to use Page Rules to force HTTPS. I have configured HSTS and submitted it for preload. I also have all port 80 connections on my server being redirected to a TLS connection. However, when fresh browsers are first trying to hit my sites over HTTP, they do not get redirected but see a CloudFlare 522 error (connection to origin server timed out). Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Here is my Nginx config (I omitted most of the 443 server block for security, but accessing site over HTTPS does work):

```
server {
    server_name www.filterlists.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://filterlists.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name filterlists.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name filterlists.com;
    root /var/www/filterlists;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first server block is missing a listen directive, but we can make things more simple and performant by combining both server_name domains into one for port 80 requests, and using a redirect instead of a rewrite.

```
server {
    # HTTP --> HTTPS
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.EXAMPLE.com EXAMPLE.com;
    return 301 https://EXAMPLE.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    # remove 'www' subdomain
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.EXAMPLE.com;
    ssl_certificate /PATH/TO/CERTIFICATE.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /PATH/TO/KEY.key;
    return 301 https://EXAMPLE.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name EXAMPLE.com;
    root /YOUR/SITE/DIRECTORY;

    ...

}
```

For this and many other Nginx configuration examples, I use [H5BP's templates](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/ssl.example.com) which cover most anything you would want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I discovered that my real problem is that my firewall was blocking port 80. That being said, your answer pointed me in the right direction to replacing rewrites with returning redirects and making sure to add a directive to ipv6 connections on port 80. Thanks!

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett Too late to help you now but if you `sudo netstat -plnt` as part of any basic troubleshooting (assumes Debian/Ubuntu server), you see what ports and services are listening, and `sudo iptables -S` will list any firewall rules. Doing these two early on has saved me a ton of effort - no more wasting time with trial and error, guessing and testing unnecessary things!